# Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Reporting' on IIS without any references in the project to it

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, telerik, iis-7.5

I have a web site on IIS. There are a lot of virtual folders with separates sites on it.

I`ve updated one of them and got "*Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Reporting, Version=6.2.13.110, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified*."

The same errors on the other virtual folder`s sites.

Stack Trace.`[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Reporting, Version=6.2.13.110, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +210
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +242
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +17
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +35
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +122

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Reporting, Version=6.2.13.110, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +12761078
   System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() +214
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +334
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath) +203
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +152
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1151

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Reporting, Version=6.2.13.110, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12881540
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12722601`

But in this project I don`t use Telerik at all. I created new site on IIS, deploy this project and one work well. But in the main one I still get the error.

What should I do to remove this issue from site with virtual folders? I have to deploy this project to it. I can`t delete it and create new one.

Any suggestions? Restart doesn`t help.

Comment: It could be that you are referencing something that in-turn references Telerik. Have you changed any AppPools (say from .NET 2 to .NET 4)?

Comment: I have played with AppPools. It didn`t help.

Comment: does the web.config refer to this dll, any web.config?

Comment: No. Any references in the project.

Comment: Is this a sub application? If so, check the web.config of the root application if there any reference to telerik.

Comment: pinoy_ISF. Yes you`re right. Somebody left web config in the main folder.

Comment: pinoy_ISF can you please write it as a anwser and I will mark it as anwser.

Comment: that's what I was asking!!!!!  When I said ANY web.config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be other Web.configs that reference the telerik assembly.  You would need to check all of them